# Powershell: Implementing an IdataReader wrapper around streamreader

Tags: powershell, streamreader, sqlbulkcopy, idatareader

I am trying to load extremely large CSV files into SQL Server using Powershell.  The code also has to apply on the fly regex replacements, allow for various delimiters, EOR, and EOF markers.  For maintenance, I would really like all of this logic to exist in Powershell without importing assemblies.

To be efficient, I know I need to use the SQLBulkCopy method.  But, all of the Powershell examples I see fill a DataTable and pass it which is not possible for me because of the file size.

I am pretty sure I need to wrap StreamReader in an Idatareader and then pass that to SQLBulkcopy.  I found a couple great examples of this implemented in C#:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FlatFileDataReader
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Is it possible to accomplish this functionality using native PowerShell without importing the C# assembly? I am specifically having a hard time converting the abstract class wrapper.

This is the code I have so far that does not pass an IdataReader and breaks on memory limits.

```
function Get-CSVDataReader()
{
param (
   [string]$path
)
    $parsedData = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
    #List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>()

    $sr = new-object IO.StreamReader($path)

    while ($line = $sr.ReadLine())
    {
        #regex replace and other logic here
        $parsedData.Add($line.Split(','))
    }

    ,$parsedData #if this was an idatareader, the comma keeps it from exploding
}

$MyReader = Get-CSVDataReader('This should not fill immediately.  It needs a Read Method.')
```

Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: I don't know about Powershell, but in C# you'd just break the large file into smaller chunks, then take chunks one at a time, fill a datatable and use SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: Isn't this a task better suited to SSIS?

Comment: I also want to use PowerShell to drive a workflow.  Having to call a set of bloated, difficult to debug, SSIS packages in the middle to do a highly dynamic load seems counter intuitive.  I am looking for a more simple, Perl-type, approach.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is use a DataReader with SqlBulkCopy you could use the ACE drivers which comes with Office 2007/2010 and is also available as a separate download to open an OLEDB connection to to CSV file, open a reader and call WriteToServer

```
$ServerInstance = "$env:computername\sql1"
$Database = "tempdb"
$tableName = "psdrive"
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;" -f $ServerInstance,$Database
$filepath = "C:\Users\Public\bin\"

get-psdrive | export-csv ./psdrive.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force

$connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$filepath`";Extended Properties=`"text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited`";"

$qry = 'select * from [psdrive.csv]'

$conn = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connString)
$conn.open()
$cmd = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($qry,$conn) 
$dr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

$bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $connectionString
$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dr)

$dr.Close()
$conn.Close()

#CREATE TABLE [dbo].[psdrive](
#   [Used] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [Free] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [CurrentLocation] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [Name] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [Provider] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [Root] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [Description] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [Credential] [varchar](1000) NULL,
#   [DisplayRoot] [varchar](1000) NULL
#)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will satisfy requirements. If I remember right ACE doesn't like unix EOF.  And the approach can't do any on the fly regex replacements or handle "information rows".  After more research it looks like powershell doesn't allow for inheritance when creating a class with New-Method.  It appears I am stuck using the DLL.

Comment: Powershell doesn't like interfaces, by this I mean you'll either need to add-type a dll or compile some code on the fly when dealing with interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm importing large CSV's by a datatable and performing batch updates after 1 million rows.

```
if ($dt.rows.count -eq 1000000) {
    $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt)
    $dt.Clear()
}
```

[Here is the link where I detail my own script on my blog](http://blog.netnerds.net/2014/07/import-large-csvs-into-sql-server-using-powershell/), but the above code outlines the basic concept. My PowerShell script took 4.x minutes to import 9 million rows from a 1.1 GB CSV. The script relied on SqlBulkCopy, [System.IO.File]::OpenText and a datatable.